# How to get autocomplete / hinting for cypress.json inside WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, cypress

Cypress is very popular e2e testing framework but apparently WebStorm does not give any hinting/suggestions when editing its configuration file (cypress.json).

**Question is how to get hinting for cypress.json in WebStorm?**

P.S. I know you can add a custom JSON schema in WebStorm and if such exists for cypress.json I could add it and get maybe the hinting. But I could not find such schema for cypress.json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cypress.json` schema is available at [Schemastore](http://schemastore.org/json/) - see https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cypress-io/cypress/develop/cli/schema/cypress.schema.json

You can download it and set up schema mappings in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs | JSON Schema Mappings**

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm that suggested solution works!

Answer (score 1):

The Cypress docs have an own section dedicated to [setting up Intelligent Code Completion in your IDE](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/intelligent-code-completion.html) (this includes full code completion for the whole API and even for your custom commands).

Regarding your question, [it advises](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/intelligent-code-completion.html#Set-up-in-your-Dev-Environment-1) to use **https://on.cypress.io/cypress.schema.json** in order to enable full hinting for `cypress.json`, as this seems to always point to the latest schema.

Answer (score -1):

Three is a paid plugin (I'm the author) for IntelliJ platform (IDEA, WebStorm etc.)
It provides out of the box the following features for the Cypress configuration file: autocomplete, hinting, validation (including validation by JSON schema) and others.

See this overview for details: https://youtu.be/Laj4zzN74Jk